# H5PY Writes Very Slow

Tags: hdf5, h5py

I have a h5py dataset like below. I want to index the records by string instead of by numeric value. So, e.g. I would be able to get the value of the first record by `dset[dset.attrs['id1']]`.

I am trying to write the attributes with the code below, but it is extremely slow. If I do a `%timeit dset.attrs[rid] = idx` in the loop a single write is about 310ms. The strings I am writing are 36 characters. I have about 100k records I need to write, which would take about 9 hours. Something must be terribly wrong? Also the CPU is pegged.

```
ids = ['id1', 'id2', 'id3']
h5 = h5py.File("/tmp/ds.h5", "w")
dset = h5.create_dataset("lds", (100000, ), dtype='float32')

for idx, id in enumerate(ids): # loop takes forever
    dset.attrs[id] = idx # takes about ~310ms
```

EDIT

Minimal "working" example.

```
for idx, rid in enumerate(range(10)):
    %timeit dset.attrs[str(rid)] = idx

10 loops, best of 3: 470 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 470 ms per loop
...
```

Nearly 0.5 second for a single write.

Comment: Which version of h5py are you using?

Comment: h5py.version.api_version  is 1.8
The code is the same except that `ids` is a set object containing all of the id strings.

Comment: What is  your `h5py.version.version`?

Comment: h5py.version.version is 2.5.0

Comment: The `%timeit` on my system (h5py 2.6.0) says: "The slowest run took 55.63 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
10000 loops, best of 3: 191 µs per loop".  I'm on OS X, Python 2.7.

Comment: Mine says 1 loop, best of 3: 392 ms per loop; linux and Python 3.5. Maybe I'll try upgrading?

Comment: Yeah, try a newer h5py for sure, and possibly see if you can upgrade your underlying `libhdf5`.  On my system  your code runs fast, like 190 microseconds per write which is 2000 times faster than yours.

Comment: Will do... thanks for taking a look.

Comment: With the same version numbers on Windows I get less than a 1ms for a single write.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `latest` value for parameter `libver`. This is a *lot* faster. So, e.g.

```
h5py.File('ds.h5', 'w', libver='latest')
```

See here: https://github.com/h5py/h5py/issues/705